# Input list of variables one at a time into the same formula to test how formula output changes

Tags: r

How I can input each variable one at a time from a list of variables with values (such as `(apples=5,6,7)`, `(oranges=9,10,4)`, `(bananas=(3,2,5)`, matching with `Trend=(1,2,3)` for `(revenue=32,44,56)`) into a model and save the summary of each model in R? For example I want `apples`, then `oranges`, then `bananas` to be tested in the following model

```r
model=gam(price~s(Trend,k=2)+s(apples,k=2),
          family="quasipoisson")
```

without having to type a new model every time for each of the variables since I have over 100 variables I want to test in this model, and only wanting to modify the model by changing out apples for other fruits.

I also want to save the output of each of the models and have that be automatically compiled into a table that will keep track of the new variable tested in the model and either the entirety of the model summary or just one specific indicator value I want from the summary (such as summary$GCV).

Comment: you need to format you question. you can use backticks ie `\`` to wrap a code. You should provide valid code ie `oranges=9,10` is not valid. either use `oranges = c(9,10)` or `oranges = list(9,10)` etc so that we know what you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a dataframe `df`, and a bunch of columns,including `Trend`, `Price`, and some fruit columns, like `apples`, `bananas`, and `oranges`. You can use `lapply()` over the column names of interest, feeding each column to a simple function that leverages `as.formula` to create the formula of interest, and returns the data of interest. Here is an exmaple:

```
f <- function(col,df) {
  form = as.formula(paste0("Price~s(Trend,k=2)+s(",col,",k=2)"))
  data.frame(col = col, gcv = gam(form, data = df, family="quasipoisson")$gcv)
}
```

Now, apply the function columns of interest, and wrap in `do.call(rbind())` to return a single table

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c("apples","bananas", "oranges"), f, df=df))
```

Output:

```
      col      gcv
1  apples 1.658002
2 bananas 1.649134
3 oranges 1.637182
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(
  Trend = sample(1:20, 100, replace=T),
  Price = sample(30:60, 100, replace=T),
  apples = sample(5:15, 100, replace=T),
  oranges = sample(2:9, 100, replace=T),
  bananas = sample(4:8, 100, replace=T)
)
```